# Passing this pointer to inner class as a weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying the figure out a way to use shared_ptr and weak_ptr in my code. I have two classes - Class One and Class Two. Two in an inner class of One. Class two's constructor takes in a weak_ptr of Class One as shown below and stores it for later use.

```
Class One  
{    
    Class Two    
    {  
    private:
      std::weak_ptr<One> m_wptrOne;

    public:
      Two(std::weak_ptr<One> wptrOne)
      {
          m_wptrOne = wptrOne;
          /* m_wptr is used later by class Two if not expired and valid ofcourse */
      }
  }; // End Class Two

  .....
  void foo()  
  {  
       std::shared_ptr sptrOne(this); 
       Two obj(sptrOne);  

    .... /* do my work */  
  } // Program crashes when foo terminates 
}; //End Class One
```

I get a crash when my function foo returns because I think "sptr" is trying to free "this" pointer thinking that it is the only owner of it.

How can I solve this problem? Or is my program architecturally incorrect? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: google `enable_shared_from_this` (C++11 / Boost for '03) to safely create a shared pointer to `this`

Comment: I did try that but it did not work. It crashes at the point I call shared_from_this()

Comment: I think shared_from_this needs that object to be created as a shared pointer in the first place itself. In my case I am creating Object One on the stack and not as a shared pointer. I don't want to make it compulsory for my library users to create the object on the heap as a shared pointer.

Comment: That is correct. If the object is created on the stack, what ownership semantics would you expect weak_ptr / shared_ptr to express? It is not possible to have a weak_ptr express weak ownership of an object with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to make it compulsory for my library users to create the object on the heap as a shared pointer.

Then your inner class *cannot* require a `weak_ptr`. The use of a `weak_ptr` *requires* the use of a `shared_ptr`; it relies on the machinery that `shared_ptr` creates to know when the pointer has been destroyed. So if you don't want users to have to use `shared_ptr`, you cannot do anything that expects the class to be wrapped in a `shared_ptr`. Like create a `weak_ptr` from it.

Therefore, you need to make your inner class independent of `weak_ptr` if you want users to be able to not create these objects on the heap.

You could try something where you force users to wrap their stack objects in a `shared_ptr` that uses a special deleter. But that'd be far more annoying than just heap allocating it.

Answer (score 1):

The below is an example of using `enable_shared_from_this` to pass weak ownership semantics from `this`.

Note that it is not possible to express weak ownership semantics to an object with automatic storage duration.

The crash you mention regarding `shared_from_this` is probably an exception of type `std::bad_weak_ptr` caused by the attempt to gain a shared_ptr from an object that is not shared.

```
#include <memory>

class One   : public std::enable_shared_from_this<One>
{    
public:
    class Two    
    {  
    private:
      std::weak_ptr<One> m_wptrOne;

    public:
      Two(std::weak_ptr<One> wptrOne)
      {
          m_wptrOne = wptrOne;
          /* m_wptr is used later by class Two if not expired and valid ofcourse */
      }
  }; // End Class Two

  //.....
  void foo()  
  {  
       std::shared_ptr<One> sptrOne = shared_from_this(); 
       Two obj(sptrOne);  

    //.... /* do my work */  
  } // Program crashes when foo terminates 
}; //End Class One


int main()
{
    auto one = std::make_shared<One>();
    one->foo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you and that solution works. But I am a library writer and how can I assume that the users of my library will create object "One" as a shared pointer on the heap. Is there any other workaround or do I need to write a factory method which will create the object on the heap and expect my users to use that factory method to create objects of class "One".

Comment: Is it possible for objects of type `Two` to outlive their creator object of type `One`? In your simplified example above it is not, so it seems the simplest solution would be to pass a reference and ignore how `One` is allocated.